# Why the pdf file cannot show the chapter?

Tags: external-files

Today,I typoset a book.

My code:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=red,unicode]{hyperref} 
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.8cm,bottom=2.5cm}

\begin{document}

   \tableofcontents
   \input{Preface}
   \input{Preface to the first edition}
   \input{Introduction}
   \input{chapter_1}
   \input{chapter_2}
   \input{chapter_3}
   \input{chapter_4}

\end{document}
```

However,the PDF file show `Preface` twice,not showing the chapter `Preface to the first edition`.So i wonder why and how to revise.

Comment: Did you use `\chapter{Preface to the first edition}` (or `\chapter*{Preface to the first edition}`) inside the corresponding file?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina,Yes,I use the `\chapter*{Preface to the first edition}` and  `\chapter*{Preface}` in two *.tex file ,repectively.

Comment: @tangshuhao, [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Ch'en Meng,Ok ,I know.

Comment: Don't use spaces in file names.  Rename the file "Preface to the first edition"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be `\input`ing them but `\include`. Further, it is better to use `frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` constructs. With these you don't have to use `\chapter*{Preface to the first edition}` but `\chapter{Preface to the first edition}` for chapters in `frontmatter` and `backmatter`. This will also take care of `proper page numbering scheme.

A sample code will be

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}   %% for times
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=red,unicode]{hyperref}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.8cm,bottom=2.5cm}

\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
   \tableofcontents
   \include{Preface}
   \include{Preface to the first edition}
 \mainmatter
   \include{Introduction}
   \include{chapter_1}
   \include{chapter_2}
   \include{chapter_3}
   \include{chapter_4}
 \backmatter  %% if any

\end{document}
```

`\include`ing has the advantage of `\includeonly` by which you can compile only one or two chapters. Ah, BTW, don't use `times` which is deprecated. Use `newtxfonts` instead say. Also, don't use file names with spaces like `Preface to the first edition`.

Comment: .thanks for your solution sincerely.However,it always show two preface in the contents.But when I put the `\chapter{Preface to the first edition}` on the `main document` it shows normally.

Comment: Harish, my congratulations for 50k :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller Thank you very much for your kindness. :)